# Chrome and Windows 10 shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, shortcuts

In Windows 10 I have created a shortcut for an application and assigned a shortcut key to that. It works fine, except when Chrome is active. When Chrome is active, shortcut does not fire. Is it possible to fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide more info. What is the application? What is the shortcut key you assigned? Do you get the same results for all shortcuts? What research have you done? What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: What's the question? Your missing a huge amount of information on your presentation of a problem. A shortcut could be many things. Describe the shortcut, how you made it, what software (if any) used to create it; a batch routine, a desktop link shortcut, a runnable script... What application does this shortcut call on or run?

Comment: It is same for all shortcuts on desktop, haven't tried placing them on start menu. By shortcut I mean a shortcut to application as in .lnk file.

Comment: Shortcut is to an application, I tried several, none of them works with chrome but works elsewhere.